# get decimal file name as hex powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd

i have a bunch of files that have filename as decimal, like 0 100, 200, 344, etc so i used this code powershell

```
"gci | sort @{Expression={[int][RegEx]::Match($_, '\d+').Value}} | %%{ $_.Name } | Select-Object -Skip 1" > Headerlist.txt
```

this take the filename as by expression order, and save into a text file, works perfectly, but how can i convert them to hex?
Like.
Name of files

0
108
314
450
.....

i want

0
6c
13A
1C2

.....

thanks!

Comment: **_PLEASE DO NOT SHOUT AT US!_** do you really think that shouting is going to get anything other than disdain? [*grin*]

Comment: I did not shout on anyone, its just my caps was on and i did not notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following one of the examples on how to convert decimal to hex from the linked answer in comments and assuming your filenames only have digits the code would be as follows, note that the use of `[RegEx]::Match($_, '\d+').Value` is unnecessary assuming the filenames only have numeric digits:

```
Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object { [int]$_.BaseName } | ForEach-Object {
    '{0:X}{1}' -f [int]$_.BaseName, $_.Extension
} | Out-File HeaderList.txt
```

You can test the code with this example:

```
([System.IO.FileInfo[]]'0.ext,100.ext,200.ext,344.ext,108.ext,314.ext'.Split(',')) |
Sort-Object { [int]$_.BaseName } | ForEach-Object {
    '{0:X}{1}' -f [int]$_.BaseName, $_.Extension
}
```